# How do I match URLs using a regex?

Tags: .net, regex, vb.net

I have string:

```
http://example.com/a b.html https://example.net/a+b+c http://example.org/one two three
```

each one link starts with http or https and contains chars like space
end of each, is the beginning of another.
How can I get

```
http://example.com/a b.html
https://example.net/a+b+c
http://example.org/one two three.html
```

using Regex ?

Comment: Unfortunately, urls are _not regular_, meaning that while you can easily get _close_, there will likely be edge cases that will break your expression. If the input to the regex is limited, this may be okay.

Answer (score 2):

This regex should find what you need:

```
https?.+?(?=http|$)
```